# How to change img src value using span tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

- I want to change the **img src** value using the **span tag** element
- I already get value for span tag but I can not find a way to change
  img src value
- Problem is the span tag embedded inside the img src
- To complete the src link span id value needed

---

- I get span tag value using bellow function

  $('#icon').text(data.icon);

It will give output as

```
03n
```

so I want to update img src as

```
<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/**span_value_shoud_be_there**.png"/>
```

I tried several way like this

```
<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/<span id='icon'></span>.png"
```

But I can not get a solution.
Appreciate your answers
Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain in more detail what the issue is and also include a [mcve]

Comment: Is image src exactly like this on the page load http://openweathermap.org/img/w/.png ? If so: href=$('img').attr('src').replace('.png',txt+'.png');$('img').attr('src',href); txt is var you already get from the icon...

Comment: @sinisake Can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get span tag value using bellow function

Using jQuery `text()` with a parameter sets the text to that parameter value. You should use it without specifying a parameter to get the text of your `<span>`. Store that text in a variable and set your image's `src` attribute accordingly.

```
let text = $('#icon').text();
yourImg.src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${text}.png`
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In **vanilla Javascript** (not jQuery), if you have an image element:

```
<img class="my-image" src="" />
```

and you would like to give that image's `src` attribute a value, you can use:

```
<script>

  const myImage = document.getElementsByClassName('my-image')[0];      
  myImage.setAttribute('src', '[VALUE HERE]');

</script>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute