# How to add dynamic content into image src url using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, email

```
<img src="https://website.example/convention?plastic_id=**{add-id-here}**&muppet_id=**{add-id-here}**">
```

I'm trying to add dynamic content (stored in an external database) into the {add-id-here} fields. Please note it's not exactly an image but more of a tracking link used for Email reporting. I am able to add it by surrounding the {add-id-here} fields with double quotes but that breaks the link all together.

Comment: Are you generating the html in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change img src value using span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257575/how-to-change-img-src-value-using-span-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can render a dynamic url through java script keep the url inside backticks **(``)** and the variable inside **${}**

```js
var addidhere="some random text"
document.getElementById("imageid").src=`https://website.example/convention?plastic_id=${addidhere}&muppet_id=${addidhere}`;
```

```html
<img src="" id="imageid">
```